# AWS MediaConverter - How do I change the names of the thumbnails generated

Tags: aws-media-convert

I am now using AWS MediaConverter to upload videos and associated thumbnails to S3. In Transcoder, which is deprecated, I could specify the format of the thumbnail images (00001.jpg,00002.jpg .....). My application logic depends on this format. In MediaConverter the thumbnails are assigned filenames : "VideoName".0000001.jpg, "VideoName".0000002.jpg ...
How can I implement my old naming convention in MediaConverter? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of variables you can use in the output filenames for MediaConvert. Available variables include filename, date+time, and other common items.  See this page for details:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/list-of-settings-variables-with-examples.html

Additionally, each output within each output group supports a 'Name modifier' variable which gets inserted into the files created by that group.   The MEdiaConvert API docs found here ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/apireference/custom-endpoints.html) also describe the available name modifiers.